# Rails TemplateRenderer render_to_string returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I have some code in my mailer application that just randomly stopped working and I cannot figure out why.

In my mailer I am doing

```
body_html =  TemplateRenderer.new.render_to_string(
  :template => "mail_templates/#{template}/template", 
  :locals => params).to_str
```

template is a valid variable and points to the proper location. But I am getting

> undefined method `to_str' for nil:NilClass"

errors on the `to_str` method because the `render_to_string` method is returning `nil`. I have never had problems with this before and I cannot figure out why it is all of a sudden not working.

Comment: What is your version of Rails. Is there a way to view what is in params when it fail. Why you don't use something like `render "mail_templates/#{template}/template", params` ?

Comment: I just realized we upgraded to Rails 4.1 recently. Something must've changed ineither TemplateRenderer or render_to_string with the update to Rails.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a discussion about this, you can read it here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14125

One of the suggested fixes is:

```
In 4.1 you also have to include ActionView::Rendering.
```

But this seems to have been patched on newer versions:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1cf4bf90251482610ef4ffc253eb542c5778c27b